# Require best Ajax session array pagination

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, session, pagination

I am using php mysql.

First on form submission I run query on mysql and get the row id -> store it in session array.

For displaying the result I have modified one php array pagination script to create pagination of session array with first,prev,next,last, Jump to page number functionality. For that pagination I have taken the reference from:

http://lotsofcode.com/php/php-array-pagination.htm

Script is working fine.

But I have two questions.

> Question 1: Is it fine to store big result in session array? if not
>   what will be the good alternative for that? (I am wondering to keep
>   first 500 result in session array and if result result is more than
>   500 then create one xml file.)
>
> Question 2: Is it possible to use ajax for pagination working with
>   session array and having functionality of first,prev,next,last, Jump
>   to page number?

If any solution is there please update me.

Thanks
Ravindra.

Comment: Can you show us your code where you store this data in a "session array" ??

Comment: while($a=mysql_fetch_array($r)){array_push($_SESSION['resIds'],$a['jsId']);}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use sessions to store large amounts of data, and I wouldnt use sessions to store data returned from a table (mysql or otherwise).

The session data is stored on the server - and held within memory - whats going to happen when you get multiple users using the same table ?

The database (mysql or otherwise) should be sufficient enough, with the correct indexes in place, to handle queries for displaying data.

I have a mysql table with 120 million records and can extract data quickly using date ranges - no speed issues what so ever.

Comment: Yes, that table is going to used by multiple users. But i dont want to fire query on database for each page. so first i fire query to get result of row id only then i want to use that ids to display result.

Comment: so you display a list of ids and the user can select each ID to get the remaining data ? if so then just grab all the data at the start and hide it (apart from the id) on the page - it will be faster and quick for the user when you show it

Comment: Let me explain in details: i am working in job board. for searching first i query on DB get the relevent result . in this query i only retrive the ids of the result row. then i create an session array to store the result id. that session array i use in pagination. on first page i get 0-19 ids from session array and fire the query with these ids to get details of the jobseeker and display on result page. for next page i use 20-39 ids from session array and again send the query with these ids to get details of next 20 jobseekers details

Comment: My suggestion is dont use Session and just return all of the data - you only query the database once then - if you have the correct indexes in place (if you are ordering by primary key then you already have) then it will be quick.

Comment: row ids which i retrive is the primary key. but i am not ordering the result on it. i am using word-ranking for primary result query so these ids are not in asc or desc order of ids. i am using ORDER BY FIELD(jsId,$array); here $array is the array of ids 0-19. so i need to fire primary query once then i get the result of ids in proper order. there is only way to use that result of ids to show details of jobseekers using array pagination. will u pl guide me in it?

Comment: The query you use to get the IDs of the results - use that same query but return all of the data not just the IDs

Comment: if we retrive all require data in primary query.  i have to display 20 results per page. cant fire primary query for each page.but how can i use that data to show in pagination?

Comment: have a look at the LIMIT function - you can keep a track of the current page and next page ...

Comment: There are lots of examples on how to do this >http://www.9lessons.info/2010/10/pagination-with-jquery-php-ajax-and.html or http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/06/paginating-your-data-with-ajax-and.html

Comment: while using the limit function i have to fire primary query for each page. that i want to avoid because that query is too heavy with more than 20 crieteria in where clause. so i dont want to query for each page. any other alternative for it?

Comment: i wouldnt store the results in a session - but maybe use the session to store the Ids if you are saying the query is to "heavy" - i would implement indexes on my table to ensure the query was more efficient

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion to implement indexes. I will do that. i gone through your ref link on 9lessions.info   Is it work  if i initially run my primary query to get the result having ids only then store that ids in jquery array (instead of storing that in session) on result page . then by using jquery ajax fire secondary query to get details of only 20 jobseekers using the jquery array ids 0-19 ?

Comment: Dear ManseUk, thanks for your guideline. i have succesfully created the pagination. In it i has'nt use session nor jquery to save ids. i saved these in xml file and use it for each page.